# My mouse cursor is moving, but i can't click properly

Tags: mouse, mouse-pointer

I have some serious problems with my Mad Catz R.A.T. 7 mouse, I can move my cursor but I can't always click on a button, or work in a program like Blender.
The hardware is okay, it works just fine on Windows on the same PC.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by **can't always click on a button**. The sensitivity is too high and you missing buttons? Update your answer with more info.

Comment: Sometimes you can't close Window by clicking the close Button on the Window.

Comment: And i'm using a mad catz Rat 7, maybe its a common problem.

Comment: You mean Mad Catz R.A.T. 7? Yep, it surely "uncompromising", according to its photo. So it misses clicks? Only on Close button or elsewhere? Many people complaining about accidental double-clicks of this model: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3j3veLA9is

Comment: Found some info regarding this mouse: https://delightlylinux.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/using-the-cyborg-r-a-t-7-with-ubuntu/ . Button freezing is also mentioned in it.

Comment: Thanks man you're awsome, it's seems to be the button freezing problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a Config file in the Directory: **usr/share/xorg.conf.d**, called **910-rat.conf**, then edit the file and paste:

**Section "InputClass"
 Identifier "R.A.T."
 MatchProduct "R.A.T.7|R.A.T.9"
 MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
 Option "Buttons" "17"
 Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 0 0 8 9 7 6 12 0 0 0 16 17"
 Option "AutoReleaseButtons" "13 14 15"
 Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection**

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my Mad Catz Rat 7 was an Button freezing issues wich seems very common on Ubuntu.

I found a youtube video, which explains how to fix this issue.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=871eM-GcdyI

Comment: If it worked for you please post your config file which resolved your issue. This will make your answer valuable. Posting link as an answer isn't proper way. Thanks.